# Defining reversibility without resorting to entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, definition, reversibility

Is it possible to define the concept of *reversible process* without using any mention to entropy?

The Wikipedia definition of reversible process seems to accomplish this by stating that:

> In thermodynamics, a reversible process is a process, involving a system and its surroundings, whose direction can be reversed by infinitesimal changes in some properties of the surroundings, such as pressure or temperature.

But what exactly is meant here by "*whose direction can be reversed by infinitesimal changes in some properties of the surroundings*"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Reversible process means that given the outside controllable mechanical, electrical, magnetic, chemical, etc., macroscopic parameters $\hat x_1,\hat x_1,\hat x_2,...,\hat x_n$  of the surroundings *and* its temperature $\hat T$ at which heat exchange can also take place any *and* all internal thermodynamic properties (parameters), say $z$, of the system at any time instant during the process can be written as a *function* of said external parameters: $z(t) = f(\hat T(t), \hat x_1(t),\hat x_2(t),...,\hat x_n(t))$. Notice the function depends only on the instantaneous values and not on the time rates of the external parameters. The $t$ in the function is just a process index by which the various consecutive stages of the thermodynamic process is marked, i.e., time.

If the function $f$ is differentiable then a linearized approximation over a short time interval $\delta t$ will give $\delta z= \frac {\partial f}{\partial T}\delta \hat T + \sum_k \frac {\partial f}{\partial \hat x_k}\delta \hat x_k$. If all $\delta \hat T$ and $\delta \hat x_k$ are small enough steps, then flipping their signs will get you back where you started from. This is the change of direction in the process you are asking about.

Comment: Using your formalism, would you be able to give an example of a process that is irreversible? Thank you

Comment: that will take a lot more to answer than a comment, so please ask a separate question

Answer (score 0):

> But what exactly is meant here by "*whose direction can be reversed by infinitesimal changes in some properties of the surroundings*"?

It means that the process is conducted under infinitesimal gradients of temperature, pressure and chemical potential. Equivalently, $T$, $P$ and $\mu$ remain *uniform* throughout the process. For example, to exchange heat reversibly is to bring the system, presumed at $T$, into contact with another system at $T+dT$. By reversing the sign of $dT$ the state retraces its path. This is possible only of $dT$ is a true differential, not a finite $\Delta T$.